# Remove elements in a row of an array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm developing an API which produces results in JSON format, when I encoded results into JSON using PHP, it shows every element in the row of the array. I use MySQL to grab data.

```
foreach($search as $item) {
    echo json_encode($item);
}
```

This will output

```
{"id":"1","name":"A","tag":"a A","url":"A"} {"id":"2","name":"B","tag":"b B","url":"B"}
```

Is there a way to dump TAG element so it won't appear in JSON encoded results?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier only selecting the columns in your SQL `SELECT` statement that are needed for the JSON output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($search as $item) {
    unset($item['tag']);
    echo json_encode($item);
}
```

you can do it by unset()

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the element from the array before `json_encode`

```
foreach($search as $item) {
    unset($item['tag']);
    echo json_encode($item);
}
```